# During an interview, how can I tell if my prospective manager is competent or incompetent?

Tags: interviewing

When it comes to interviews, majority of the weight is on the applicant and whether the prospective applicant is competent enough to do the job and be a good fit within the existing team. To flip sides, what key signs should an applicant be on the lookout for to see if the hiring manager is competent and successful in managing a team of employees? I usually ask hiring managers "*What's their management style like?*" and I usually receive generic answers. Is there a better question I should be asking?

Comment: What constitutes "competent" and "successful" is pretty subjective. One employee might think a manager is excels at both whereas another might think the exact opposite. And both of them may have equally valid POV's as well. But, to answer your question..  I guess you could ask "why should I work here as opposed to another company?" and see what they say idk.

Comment: @neubert been better for the OP to have corrected their error, that way they can learn...

Comment: I think this has the seed of a really great question. Is it possible to edit it to be a little more specific? Myself, I usually ask about the beureaucracy - how do you get reimbursed for travel expenses etc... If it is a company worth working for, they have got their stuff in order. If you start getting "you have to call our service center in New Delhi" it is a red flag...